# How to inherit in java

Tags: java

I have the following in method in class 1:

```
public void makeFrame()
{
  frame = new JFrame("BorderLayout ");//create frame

  xxxxxx
  xxxx
  xxxxx

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    p1.add(button5);
    button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                            **if (q==2) {
                        label2.setText("Correct!");
                        button6.setEnabled(false); 
                      }
                        else {
                            label2.setText("Wrong!!");
                            if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
                          ((JButton)e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
                       }**
                    }
                    }
                });
}
```

But I want to move the if statement into a different class by inheritance/implements:

```
class 2 extends class 1 or
class 2 inplements class 1
```

Could someone please tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: `class SomeActionListener implements ActionListener`?

Comment: ActionListener is in class 1

Comment: Which "logic" are your talking about?  The button?  The listener?  The code that adds the listener to the button?

Comment: The code that adds the listener to the button.

Comment: You need to give more information. What logic specifically do you want to move to a base class. Why do you want to move it there? _What problems are you having in trying to move it?_ (that's the big one).

Comment: `"But I want to move the logic into a different class by inheritance:"` -- In general, this is not a reason to use inheritance. If you could be more specific, we could re-open your question and give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I was hoping for more information, more detail. I still don't see what you mean to do and how inheritance fits in.

Comment: Is it possible to move the if statement into another class? It doesn't have to use inheritance.

Comment: @user3490456: yes, create a class that implementss ActionListener as Robert Beltran has already suggested. If you're getting an error, then fix it. But don't try to have your listener class extend your GUI class, just have it implement ActionListener, or better, extend AbstractAction.

Comment: Moving the code isn't an end, it's a means to an end. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I've created a game and want to separate the game logic and the GUI and have them in different classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
package testProject;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainClass {

    public void makeFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2,2 ));
        JButton button = new JButton();
        panel.add( button );
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        button.addActionListener( new MyActionListener( label, button) );
    }
}

package testProject;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;

    public MyActionListener( JLabel label, JButton button ) {
        this.button = button;
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           label.setText("Sample text");
           button.setEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

That should do it. No inheritance required.

Comment: I get the error code interface expected here when I tried to implement class 1

Comment: @user3490456: the general advice here is correct. If you're getting an error, then fix it depending on what the error is.